# Heroku Application Error Occur

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

## Heroku Application error

I don't understand why this will be happen.Can anyone tell me why this will be happening...?

**Application Error**

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

## Logs

```
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.882761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.883859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-01-15T09:12:41.913025+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-15T09:12:41.913025+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:49194
2014-01-15T09:12:41.913025+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-01-15T09:12:41.913025+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-15T09:12:41.913025+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-15T09:12:43.365057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-15T09:12:43.388570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-15T09:34:57.545417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.36.135.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:34:58.737978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.36.135.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:39:33.012548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:39:37.499410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:39:37.937049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:39:31.872794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:40:42.463904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:40:43.143297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T09:43:54.807645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-01-15T09:43:57.879492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 4381 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': /app/app/models/banners.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5 maximum: 25}
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                 ^
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.873725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.874393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-01-15T09:44:00.898780+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-15T09:44:00.898780+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:4381
2014-01-15T09:44:00.898780+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-01-15T09:44:00.898780+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-15T09:44:00.898780+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-15T09:44:00.875890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:44:02.058347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-15T09:44:02.077676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-15T09:44:13.799826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=scitech.herokuapp.com fwd="39.42.60.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the `banners.rb` file. Line `validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5 maximum: 25}` should be

`validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 25}`