# Ruby on Rails uploading to Heroku then crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, crash

I'm able to push my files to Heroku, but the app crashes when it's online. I tried changing the Bootstrap-Sass gem but that didn't seem to work.
I've run the heroku logs, and things seem to fall apart here:

```
←[36m2014-02-04T10:26:56.745539+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
←[36m2014-02-04T10:26:56.745356+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
←[36m2014-02-04T10:26:57.882133+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2014-02-04T10:26:57.891144+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can't find anywhere that is `config.ru:3` and was hoping you could help.

https://github.com/Thefoodie/P...

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems your config is not loaded on heroku see the link for solution over it...

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763609/why-config-folder-is-not-pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763609/why-config-folder-is-not-pushed/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem here: [Heroku Application Error Occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134557/heroku-application-error-occur)

Seems there is something wrong with your code - do you have any more of the logs you could share? You may wish to add the [logentries add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) to give a better log UI

You'll typically find errors in the `config.rb` & similar files from a deeper issue in your app. If you get back with your extended logs, we'll be in a better position to provide a specific solution